# verificar numero repetido dentro do array c#

Tags: c#

Eu criei um array pré definido com alguns números, e quero saber quantos numeros repetidos tem no array. mas ele só está retornando o tamanho do array e não qtd de numeros repetidos. e também queria remover os numeros repetido.

```
int[] array1 = { 2, 5, 8, 10, 2, 23, 2, 4, 5, 8, 8 };
int contador=0;

for(int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < array1.Length; j++)
    {
        if (array1[j] == array1[i])
        {
            contador++;
            break;

        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Total de numeros repetidos -> " + contador);
```

Comment: Defina "quantos números repetidos", isto pode ser interpretado de várias formas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Atribua seu array dentro de um HashSet, pois o mesmo não aceita valores repetidos, e depois você compara os tamanhos de ambos e vai saber quantos valores era repetido:

```
int[] array1 = { 2, 5, 8, 10, 2, 23, 2, 4, 5, 8, 8 };
var meuHashSet = new HashSet<int>(array1);
var valoresRepetidos = array1.Length - meuHashSet.Count;
```

Comment: se eu entendi meuHashSet  recebe meu array já removendo os numeros repetidos,logo ele tem um novo tamanho? e valoresRepetidos  recebe meuHashSet   com novo tamanho, menos o tamanho que tinha meu array1 .

Comment: O .Lenth e o .Count vai contar quantos elementos possui a sua coleção, logo a subtração do tamanho do Hash com o array normal vai te dizer a quantidade de valores que eram repetidos.

Comment: Sim, o meuHashSet já vai "remover" os valores repetidos direto.

Comment: Agora entendi ficou bem claro e nem precisei mais usar laços

Answer (score 3):

Como comentado,

> **Manieiro**:
>   Defina "quantos números repetidos", isto pode ser interpretado de
>   várias formas.

A resposta proposta apresenta uma solução que depende exatamente de qual pergunta está sendo feita.

> **Gabriel Coletta**
>
> ```
> int[] array1 = { 2, 5, 8, 10, 2, 23, 2, 4, 5, 8, 8 };
> var meuHashSet = new HashSet<int>(array1);
> var valoresRepetidos = array1.Length - meuHashSet.Count;
> ```

O resultado apresentado é **5**, resultado da diferença do tamanho original do `Array` subtraído de seu `Distinct`, que aliás também pode ser escrito da seguinte forma usando o `Linq`

```
int[] array1 = { 2, 5, 8, 10, 2, 23, 2, 4, 5, 8, 8 };
var quantidadeRepetidos = array1.Length - array1.Distinct().Count();
```

Contudo, chegamos a um ponto subjetivo, **5** na verdade representa a quantidade de repetições dos valores após suas primeiras ocorrências, em outras palavras, **5** é igual quantidade de duplicatas ou recorrências.

Porém ao observarmos o conjunto original `[2, 5, 8, 10, 2, 23, 2, 4, 5, 8, 8]`, podemos ver que ele possui possui **8** elementos de valores repetidos (que possuem mais de uma ocorrência). O que pode ser constado com mais facilidade ao reorganizar e remover as ocorrências únicas
`[2,2,2,5,5,8,8,8]`. E essa diferença impacta muito no objetivo da consulta e o que você pretende fazer com esse resultado.

Mas, a quantidade de números repetidos também pode ter como objetivo, saber a quantidade de números que tiveram mais de uma ocorrência, no caso `[2,5,8]`.

Abaixo deixo um script de exemplo apenas para demonstrar como poderia responder às variações de interpretação de acordo com o objetivo especificado, utilizando algumas listas para facilitar a manipulação e um único `for()`.

```
int[] arrayOrignal = { 2, 5, 8, 10, 2, 23, 2, 4, 5, 8, 8 };

var listUnicos = new List<int>();
var listRepetem = new List<int>();
var listDuplicatas = new List<int>();

int tamanho = arrayOrignal.Length;

for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
{
    var elemento = arrayOrignal[i];

    if (arrayOrignal.Where(x => x.Equals(elemento)).Count().Equals(1))
        listUnicos.Add(elemento);
    else if (!listRepetem.Contains(elemento))
        listRepetem.Add(elemento);
    else
        listDuplicatas.Add(elemento);
}

//[2, 5, 8, 10, 23, 4] -> 6 valores distintos
int[] arrayDistinto = arrayOrignal.Distinct().ToArray();

//[10, 23, 4] -> 3 valoes únicos
int[] arrayUnicos = listUnicos.ToArray();

//[2, 5, 8] ->  3 valores que repetem 
int[] arrayRepetem = listRepetem.ToArray();

//[2, 2, 5, 8, 8] -> 5 valores recorrentes
int[] arrayDuplicatas = listDuplicatas.ToArray();

//[2, 5, 8, 2, 2, 5, 8, 8] -> 8 valores repetidos
int[] arrayRepetidos = arrayOrignal.Where(x => listDuplicatas.Contains(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Muito boa a observação sobre minha resposta, fico grato por ela, +1

Comment: @GabrielColetta, Legal que você gostou e não entendeu como uma crítica a sua resposta, o meu objetivo era apenas deixar uma observação relacionada à pergunta do AP.

Answer (score 1):

Se quiser utilizar [linq](/questions/tagged/linq) também consegue extrair as duas informações:

Buscar os itens e não trazer as repetições:

```
int[] array1 = { 2, 5, 8, 10, 2, 23, 2, 4, 5, 8, 8 };

int[] arraySemRepeticao = array1.Distinct().ToArray();
```

Agrupar os itens e contar a quantidade de repetições:

```
int[] array1 = { 2, 5, 8, 10, 2, 23, 2, 4, 5, 8, 8 };

var arrayAgrupadosRepeticaoCount = array1
             .GroupBy(x => x)
             .Select(a => new
               {
                  Item = a.Key,
                  Quant = a.Count()
               })
             .ToArray();
```

---

[Veja funcionando em dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/P7hk85)

Comment: Muito legal isso ...!

Answer (score 0):

Você está cometendo dois erros no seu código:

O primeiro é que o laço está checando o próprio número, ou seja, quando i e j são iguais ele compara o mesmo número.
O segundo erro é o break, ao encontrar um número repetido não deveria interromper o laço.

```
int[] array1 = { 2, 5, 8, 10, 2, 23, 2, 4, 5, 8, 8 };
int contador=0;

for(int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
{
    for(int j = i; j < array1.Length; j++)
    {
        if (i != j && array1[j] == array1[i])
            contador++;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Total de numeros repetidos -> " + contador);
```

Comment: uhmm, sua testei isso mas retorna 14 numeros repetidos, não faz sentido

Comment: @CezarMdlosci Sim desculpa esqueci de considerar que o segundo laço está varrendo todos os elementos assim contando os números repetidos mais de uma vez

Answer (score 0):

Você sempre está comparando dois números iguais por isso o contador no final das contas tem o mesmo valor do length. Se você não quiser mudar a estrutura do seu código, sugiro fazer essas alterações:

```
    int[] array1 = { 2, 5, 8, 10, 2, 23, 2, 4, 5, 8, 8 };
    int contador=0;

    for(int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < array1.Length; j++)
        {
            if (j != i && array1[j] == array1[i])
            {
                contador++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Total de numeros repetidos -> " + contador); //R:5 = 2, 2, 5, 8, 8
```

Answer (score -1):

na verdade vc esta comparando os numero do laço de repetição e não do array **int[] array1**, você tem que armazenar o valor do array em um variavel, e dentro do **if** você fazer o comparação entre elas e **se** elas tiverem o mesmo valor incrementar o **contador++**