# como contar inteiros num vetor em c#

Tags: c#

Preciso de ajuda para executar este exercício em c#:

> 6. Elabore um programa que conte o número de vezes que cada elemento ocorre num vetor de N inteiros. Por exemplo, no vetor A:
>      `A = {4,2,5,4,3,5,2,2,4}`
>      4 ocorre três vezes; 2 ocorre três vezes; etc.

Comment: velho eu não manjo de C# mais a forma que eu visualizei é assim: Você conta quantos números tem o vetor e verificar um a um e por na variável tipo
`for A[1] to N do
 if A[1] = A[2] then
  S := A[1] ocorre N vezes;
mostre S`

Comment: já tentou algum código ? há alguma limitação imposta pelo conteúdo programático ?

Comment: Aqui tem outra questão semelhante e com outras abordagens para você estudar
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/271802/verificar-numero-repetido-dentro-do-array-c

Comment: Possível duplicata de [verificar numero repetido dentro do array c#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/271802/verificar-numero-repetido-dentro-do-array-c)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar LINQ. Fazer um código simples, legível, agradável e aproveitar o tempo livre pra ir tomar um café.

Leia [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/273878/18246) para entender como funciona o método **`GroupBy`**, nela tem tudo explicadinho e qualquer dúvida mais específica você pode deixar um comentário.

[Nesta resposta tem um outro exemplo de uso do **`GroupBy`**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/176865/18246).

```
static void Main()
{
    var a = new [] { 4, 2, 5, 4, 3, 5, 2, 2, 4 };   
    var group = a.GroupBy(i => i).Select(e => new 
    {
        Numero = e.Key,
        Contagem = e.Count()
    });

    foreach(var g in group)
        Console.WriteLine($"O número {g.Numero} aparece {g.Contagem} vezes no array");
}
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZUbltw)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

As vezes gosto de fazer essas questões de exercícios que aparecem, só por lembranças da faculdade, mas fico com receio de, ao invés de ajudar, te atrapalhar (te dando uma cola pra resolver a tarefa).

Como eu imagino que haja limitações do conteúdo... fiz utilizando apenas `array`, `for` e `int`.

Espero que você consiga entender e aprender o código ao invés de só copiar e colar pra ganhar a nota. Não tenho muita didática, mas tentei comentar o código pra ficar mais claro:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] vetor = new int[] {4,2,5,4,3,5,2,2,4}; //Vetor informado
        int[] ns = new int[vetor.Length]; //Vetor que vai armazenar os números contados, de forma distinta

        int nDistintos = 0; //Variável para armazenar a quantidade de números distintos

        for (int i = 0; i < vetor.Length; i++) //Percorrer todo o vetor
        {
            int flagRepetido = 0; //flag para controlar se o número já foi contado
            for (int k = 0; k < nDistintos; k++) //Percorrer o vetor de números já contados
            {
                if (ns[k] == vetor[i])
                    flagRepetido = 1; //Se o número atual já estiver no vetor de números contados, marca a flag como 1
            }

            if (flagRepetido == 0) //Se a flag for 0, conta...
            {
                int q = 0; //Variável pra somar toda vez que o número aparecer no vetor
                for (int j = i ; j < vetor.Length; j++) //Percorro o vetor informado novamente. (Repare que o j inicia com valor de i, pois não é necessário percorrer os números anteriores que já foram calculados)
                {
                    if (vetor[j] == vetor[i]) //Se o número for igual ao número da posição atual, incrementa a váriavel
                        q++;
                }

                ns[nDistintos] = vetor[i]; //Armazeno o número que foi calculado
                nDistintos++; //incremento a variável de números distintos
                Console.WriteLine("Numero " +  vetor[i] + " aparece " + q + " vezes");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Resultado:

```
Numero 4 aparece 3 vezes
Numero 2 aparece 3 vezes
Numero 5 aparece 2 vezes
Numero 3 aparece 1 vezes
```

Veja no [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/E9uXWM)

ps. Fiz também um que armazena todos os cálculos para depois imprimir: [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CIp0eC)

Answer (score 0):

Eu cheguei nessa solução, espero ajudar!

```
static void Ex_28()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n______ Ex 28 ______\n");
        Console.Write("Insira a quantidade de elementos a serem armazenados na matriz: ");
        int qtdeElementos = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] arrayElementos = new int[qtdeElementos];
        
        Console.WriteLine("Insira {0} elementos na matriz: ", qtdeElementos);
        int elementos = 0;
        int frequencia = 1;
        while(elementos < qtdeElementos)
        {
            Console.Write("elemento {0}: ",elementos);
            arrayElementos[elementos] = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            elementos ++;
        }
       
        Array.Sort(arrayElementos);

        Console.WriteLine("A Frequência de todos os elementos da Matriz: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayElementos.Length ; i++)
        {   
            if(i < arrayElementos.Length-1)
            {
                if(arrayElementos[i] == arrayElementos[i+1])
                    frequencia++;
                else
                {
                    if(frequencia > 1)    
                        Console.WriteLine($"{arrayElementos[i]} ocorre {frequencia} vezes");
                    
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine($"{arrayElementos[i]} ocorre {frequencia} vez");
                    
                    frequencia = 1;
                }
                
            }
            else
            {
                if(frequencia > 1)    
                    Console.WriteLine($"{arrayElementos[i]} ocorre {frequencia} vezes");
                    
                else
                    Console.WriteLine($"{arrayElementos[i]} ocorre {frequencia} vez");
                
                frequencia = 1;
            }
        }                       
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```